Creating new and separate layer from hole(s) in multiple layers in QGIS

I am trying to create a new layer that fits perfectly into the hole in the picture below. All of the orange shapes are different layers.

With another layer covering that 'hole' you can use QGIS  Symmetrical Difference https://youtu.be/SkoenRWSEPY?si=7kz3oCL5MJQvCLPi&t=116

My start layer:


Delete holes:



Difference the delete hole layer with your start layer to create polygons where there were holes:


If you want to you can Merge the difference layer with your start layer, or edit and copy and paste the polygons to your start layer.
